# How to hide Left/Right Menu in Joomla 1.6.x?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I am using Joomla 1.7.2 with default theme "Beez2 - Default". I have created a component with name as com_sample which has link 'index.php?option=com_sample'. When i go to this link, i can see the output of the component 'sample'.

But on the left side there are few menus like User Menu, About Joomla, This Site. I want to remove that whole vertical panel so that i can use more space for my sample component.

I tried to search in administrator panel and on google but cant find anything to remove left panel.
How can i remove that panel? what code should i write in sample component file to make it disappear the left panel..

Please guide me.... thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Have you tried to `disable menu module` for that specific component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't touch any code, this is a built in behavior in Joomla. You can turn all modules on and off of a particular menu item by changing the menu assignment. It's pretty simple.

1. Make sure you have a menu item created for the page you want to look at. This is a requirement as Joomla uses the menu items to control module display. You may need to create a new menu without a display module, but it can be in any menu as long as it is published.
2. Go to the module manager and for each module you want to remove from the page, change the menu assignment. You can select a module to display on All pages, only on selected pages, except on selected pages, and on no pages.

Easy as that.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the same technique for my joomla component for more than 18 months now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this my friend !

Some of the ways are :

Edit the index.php file from the back end, remove the code at source....

Disable the relevant module from the control panel....

Keep experimenting your work finally you will get there ..